# How can I include a transformed to HTML markdown file in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I use {% include something.md %} and jekyll does it literally without transforming md to html. How do I enable the transformation? So that I get the content of something.md transformed to HTML included rather than what's immediately in that file (MD content)?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% capture fileContent %}
  {% include something.md %}
{% endcapture %}

{{ fileContent | markdownify }}
```

Comment: That doesnt account for stripping off the front matter part. I am only interested in the content.

Comment: You are not supposed to include documents with front matter but only fragments.